# how to find next day using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was tried to find next day using javascript it working for static date perfect, but not worked for dynamic date.

Also work for date between 1 to 12 and give me perfect output for it, not work for high date then 12

Please help me to solve this problem!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function next_day() { 
 // var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
 var textbox_Value = document.getElementById('date').value;
 console.log("input date : " + textbox_Value);
 var fDate = new Date(textbox_Value.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") ); //change date formate mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy
 var dayWithSlashes = (fDate.getDate()) + '/' + (fDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + fDate.getFullYear();
 console.log("Foramat changed date : " + dayWithSlashes);
 var day_in_js_format = new Date(dayWithSlashes); 
 console.log("convert in date format : " + day_in_js_format);
 day_in_js_format.setDate(day_in_js_format.getDate() + 1);
 console.log("day_in_js_format++  : " + day_in_js_format);
 var final_Result = (day_in_js_format.getDate()) + '/' + (day_in_js_format.getMonth()+1) + '/' + day_in_js_format.getFullYear();
 console.log("next day : " + final_Result);
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Next day using javascript
 </title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container fix-top">
  <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
   <legend>Form title</legend>
  
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Next day</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Input field">
   </div>      
  
   <button type="button" onclick="next_day();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
 
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Symptons say, that you've mixed months and dates when creating a date ...

Comment: Don't use a non-standard dd/mm/yyyy format when constructing the date object. Use yyyy-mm-dd instead.

Comment: i didn't mixed months and dates you please check your log for better understanding

Comment: How? We don't know, what you actually have entered to the text box.

Comment: i enter 10/09/2016 as date it give you alert with 11/09/2016 but when i enter 15/09/2016 then it give you output NaN/NaN/NaN please check

Comment: "_i didn't mixed months and dates_" But you just did ...

Comment: Dear teemu, can you please explain me my mistake??

Comment: Your *own code* says that the input is expected to be mm/dd/yyyy. You're passing it dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: but later i change the format of date

Comment: Nope, `.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")` doesn't change anything in `15/09/2016`. Do you have a hunch, why it doesn't? When you figure out that, you can also fix the month/date order in `dayWithSlashes = (fDate.getDate()) + '/' + (fDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + fDate.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 0):

Function to add days to a date:

```
    function addDays(dtRef, intDays) {
        if ( !(typeof dtRef == "object"
            && typeof dtRef['setDate'] == "function"
            && typeof dtRef['getDate'] == "function") ) {
            dtRef = new Date();
        }
        if ( typeof intDays != "number" ) {
            intDays = 1;
        }
        dtRef.setDate(dtRef.getDate() + intDays);
        return dtRef;
    };
```

You can call this function with no parameters and it will use the current date with a day offset of +1.  Or you can pass in the date and offset in days and it will return the new date.

Comment: Thanks sir but it not work for formate dd/mm/yyyy its work as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: You need to supply the function a valid javascript date, the function returns a date object which will be correct and you can get everything you need from that.